# jQuery post comparison not working as expected

Tags: jquery

The following code is not working as I expected.

```
$.post("submitpackages.php", {inoofads:z, ivaliddays:y, country:"india", })
   .done(function(data){
     alert(data);
     if(data=="true"){
       alert("true1"); 
       $("#success").show();
       $("#error").hide(); 
     }else{
       alert("false1");
       $("#success").hide();
       $("#error").show();         
     }
  });
```

I echo "true" in `submitpackages.php`. In the post, `alert(data)` prints true and then it goes to else condition and prints false1 instead of printing true1. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: try '===' instead of '=='

Comment: show us , how you are returning from `submitpackages.php`

Answer (score 0):

No need quotation.
please try this one,

```
if(data==true) {
 your code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure what you `submitpackages.php` is actually returning I'm going to guess its returning a boolean value.

The following will alert "true" then test positive for tests 2 and 4:

```
  var t = true
  alert(t)
  if(t=="true")
     alert("1")
  if(t==true)
     alert("2")
  if(t==="true")
     alert("3")
  if(t)
     alert("4")
```

Changing `var t = true` to var `t = "true"` will still alert "true" but now tests positive for 1, 3, and 4.

Comment: Just a note: if you are returning a string, test 4 returns true for both "true" and "false" since all it is testing is that a value for t exists. `if(!t)` will only work correctly if t is set to false, not "false"

Answer (score 0):

the problem is
the length of the echoed values differs from what I am checking it with. The echoed values length is higher.
so I used trim()

```
$.post("submitpackages.php", {inoofads:z, ivaliddays:y, country:"india", })
.done(function(data){
 alert(data);
 if(data.trim()=="true"){
   alert("true1"); 
   $("#success").show();
   $("#error").hide(); 
  }else{
   alert("false1");
   $("#success").hide();
   $("#error").show();         
  }
 });
```